# Category (self referencing), Product and Brand. How to fetch the brands associated to each category?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three models: Category, Product and Brand. The Category is self referencing. I would like to fetch the name brands associated to each categoriy **in hierarchical way** Any help?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Brand` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides START WITH and CONNECT BY clauses to deal with hierarchical structure. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support these clauses. However, you can do the same with somewhat complex query mentioned [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

Alternatively, you can write your business logic to iterate the category table and fetch products for each category.